# After edit order set user name guest

Tags: edit-order

When I try to edit an order in the Magento backend. After order edited the username setted Guest, but in parent order usernames set John.

I have order [s1.micp.ru/UQcmB.png](http://s1.micp.ru/UQcmB.png) In order user name is TEST after I edited order the user name setted Guest [s3.micp.ru/Acx6y.png](http://s3.micp.ru/Acx6y.png) but i didn't change username

How can i fix it?

Comment: Are you saying the user submits the order with their name but you want to change it to guest?

Comment: I have order [link]http://s1.micp.ru/UQcmB.png In order user name is TEST
after I edited order the user name setted Guest [link] http://s3.micp.ru/Acx6y.png
but i didn't change username
@brentwpeterson

Comment: It's not normal behavior. And rewrite core models is not very good solution. You need to determine why does it happen. When I press EDIT order - I'm getting page with my account details. They are already exist. Could you show us what's happening after pressing button EDIT (please provide screenshot), if you still interested in resolving your problem properly.

Comment: @zhartaunik [link]http://s2.micp.ru/G645w.png

Answer (score 0):

I changed method setAccountData in Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create from

```
    public function setAccountData($accountData)
{
    $customer   = $this->getQuote()->getCustomer();
    $form       = $this->_getCustomerForm();
    $form->setEntity($customer);

    // emulate request
    $request = $form->prepareRequest($accountData);
    $data    = $form->extractData($request);

    $form->restoreData($data);

    $data = array();
    foreach ($form->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
        $code = sprintf('customer_%s', $attribute->getAttributeCode());
        $data[$code] = $customer->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode());
    }


    if (isset($data['customer_group_id'])) {
        $groupModel = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($data['customer_group_id']);
        $data['customer_tax_class_id'] = $groupModel->getTaxClassId();
        $this->setRecollect(true);
    }

    $this->getQuote()->addData($data);
    return $this;
}
```

to

```
    public function setAccountData($accountData)
{
    $customer   = $this->getQuote()->getCustomer();
    $form       = $this->_getCustomerForm();
    $form->setEntity($customer);

    // emulate request
    $request = $form->prepareRequest($accountData);
    $data    = $form->extractData($request);

    $form->restoreData($data);

    $data = array();
    foreach ($form->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
        $code = sprintf('customer_%s', $attribute->getAttributeCode());
        $data[$code] = $customer->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode());
    }

    if(!$data['customer_firstname'])
    {
        $data['customer_firstname'] = $this->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname().' '.$this->getBillingAddress()->getLastname();
        if(!$data['customer_firstname'])
        {
            $data['customer_firstname'] = $this->getShippingAddress()->getFirstname().' '.$this->getShippingAddress()->getLastname();
        }
    }   

    if (isset($data['customer_group_id'])) {
        $groupModel = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($data['customer_group_id']);
        $data['customer_tax_class_id'] = $groupModel->getTaxClassId();
        $this->setRecollect(true);
    }

    $this->getQuote()->addData($data);
    return $this;
}
```

And it works